# Cumulative linux kernel changelogs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, logs

You know how it goes when you build your own kernels but not as your main occupation... By the time you realise some new quirk could be due to a kernel regression, there have already been more than a few point releases.

Is there an interface somewhere where you can enter your current kernel version and some later version, in order to get the combined changelog listing all changes? I think this could be a simple (browser) script that just pulls in each individual changelog and concatenates them?

EDIT: I'm pretty certain I saw an answer flash by that showed how to get a combined changelog via a git webinterface, which sounds like exactly what I want (and plausible because the changelogs do look like `git log` output). The answer is gone, however... please repost it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211809/how-to-compare-two-tags-with-git

Comment: What changelogs are you trying to combine? The raw git logs, or something else?

Comment: Changelogs like the one for the kernel build I'm using ATM: https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.14.193 . I could probably write a little script that loads and concatenates all the `https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/vX.x/ChangeLog-X.Y.Z` URLs that match the requested range and then hands the result to my browser. Something a little more elaborate than that would be nicer of course.